# Is there a way to upgrade to a different v2 instance type without downtime?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Is it possible to create a read replica/failover, shut down the master and switch the slave instance to master, upgrade the old master and then make it the new master again - upgrading up or down instance types without downtime?

I took a look at failovers, but they appear to only activate when the master is shut down for maintenance and not when the master is shut down.

If not, is this feature in the works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upgrade from 1st Generation to 2nd Generation, but you have to create a new instance. You can however use the import and export function to transfer the data (storing them temporary in the Cloud Storage).

For the transfer period you could use a read-only replica to avoid changes.

Note that you might need to make small or bigger changes to your code as the access is different in many ways.